# My code is functionally okay, but I want to minimize the line of code. Is there any way to make the following code in two or less line of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

#### Want to minimize the lines of code

This code takes degrees Celsius in input and gives Fahrenheit in output. It's working fine, I just want to minimize the size of this code but I have some restriction here; need to use both sting and list, need to take user input and need to convert list to sting at last.

**Requirements:**

1. Input and output must be *string*, and take user input.
2. Internally, it will be stored in a *list*.
3. And finally, the output must be in *string* format.

```py
listA = []
listA.extend(['Fahrenheit =',eval(str(input('Enter Temperature in celsius(C)) :: ')).lower().replace('c', '* (9/5) + 32'))])
print(' '.join(map(str,listA)))
```

**Output**
[image: Code Output]

Comment: what's the purpose behind the list requirement ? seems like it's only taking one input so no real need for the list

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this. I try not using `eval` as much as possible. `eval` can be dangerous when executing untrusted strings.

```
'Fahrenheit = '+str(float(input().strip('cC'))*(9/5) +32)
# 'Fahrenheit = 131.9'
```

Comment: It's binding to use **list**.

Comment: Why do you even need to use a list?

Comment: I have to store the value for further use purposes.

Comment: @Kitto you can do that without a list

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, I can but there is a binding to use list.

Comment: @Ch3steR, thank you for your valuable reply. It works for lowercase 'c' only. How can I make the code usable for both lower and uppercase?

Comment: Use `.strip('cC')` @KittoMi

Comment: @Ch3steR Yes, it's working. But please give me some suggestions to meet the requirement.

Comment: I don't see a reason to use a *list* here. Using a list just to store one value makes no sense to me. If really want to use a list. Just append the value to whichever list you want to use or `[]+['Fahrenheit = '+str(float(input().strip('cC'))*(9/5) +32)]`

Comment: @Kitto what do you mean binding? Please show us your complete assignment. All we're doing is answering the question you initially asked, and says nothing about a list being required